# CDN for SAPUI5 access - or alternate way to get fastest local access

Tags: sapui5

was wondering if anyone had a solution (hopefully simple) for how to change the repository that a SAPUI5 app pulls from.

i.e. when I'm accessing my app (might be hosted anywhere, but for argument's sake lets say on HCP in EU) and I'm in the EU, it makes sense to use the EU repository:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-cachebuster/sap-ui-core.js

when in the US however, I'm going to get much better performance if I use the US repository:

https://sapui5.us1.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-cachebuster/sap-ui-core.js

But short of having a US app and a EU app, how can I achieve this? I don't want to pop-up a request for the user to allow their browser to know where they are via using HTML Geo capabilities http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html and it seems most solutions to map IP addresses to location charge a fee (which I don't want to have to pay)

The standard way for this sort of thing on the web (afaik) would be just to use one address and have a CDN sort it out for you.

This doesn't seem to have happened for SAPUI5.

Anyone know why not? Or perhaps it has, and I just don't know about it, that would also be a very happily received answer.

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm not sure if this will allow you to replace the repository URL (since it's one of the first things that gets loaded in your page) but a quick and really dirty, muddy, soggy solution to roughly distinguish the Americas, EMEA and ASIAPAC zones could be to use the current user's timezone... A CDN would be *much* better of course but hey, at least this is a free solution too ;-)

Comment: You could host your app on AWS (CloudFront) and thereby get CDN capabilities... All depends on what your app does of course.

Comment: @JasonScott App has to run on SAP HCP as is SuccessFactors extension, but wanted way to improve response based on user location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now, as of January 2015 there is such a CDN (with geo routing) implemented for OpenUI5 (or more specifically, for everything below the URL https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com).

It does not only serve the data from the closest SAP data center (Germany, USA, Australia), but uses the popular Akamai CDN technology on top, which provides thousands of servers around the world.

See http://openui5.tumblr.com/post/108835000027/openui5-in-your-neighborhood-a-true-cdn-has-gone for more details.

Answer (score 1):

there is currently no such CDN with automatic routing to the closest server, sorry.
Reasons? Lack of time, money, demand...

There may be even free offerings for Open Source libs, but the total of UI5 is larger than your typical JS lib, so I'm not sure they would want it. And in older IE versions the cross-domain loading wasn't working anyway due to missing CORS support, hence a local deployment was preferred. And custom-tailored minimized runtimes for apps are the best for good performance, this is also not something a CDN can deliver. So currently there is no such thing even though it would be obviously good to have.

Comment: have seen some big libraries on https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs, has it been tried before?

Comment: Hi Andreas, great to see you on SO. Whilst this certainly answers the q is there a CDN, unfortunately it's not helping my app run faster :( Think I'll stick with code changes to US DC deploy and EU deploy and get users to connect to system closest to them

Comment: Hi John and Chris,
no, it hasn't been tried.
But UI5 needs CORS to properly load resources and I doubt the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header can be set for GitHub resources.
As I understand, cdnjs.cloudflare.com is supposed to be used to load the libs and Cloudflare only forwards the headers, so we need them on the original server.
Of course anyone is free to deploy their own copy of UI5 on a CORS-enabled server and directly use Cloudflare for it, but of course I understand this is expected from the library owners.
We'll try to investigate.

Comment: I note that SuccessFactors currently uses a CDN - Akamai for its distribution of elearning content. Given the already existing arrangement (and potential for SuccessFactors to start moving towards UI5 builds) it could be a way forward.

Comment: Yeah, in fact I heard some internal talk about using real CDNs recently, so maybe there is something coming up.

Answer (score 0):

**UI5 will load awesome fast** if is part of a **real app**. Real app means a installable app from an App Store were the UI5 library is part of the app itself and not loaded from a server. That is **the real destiny of UI5** and not putting it on a Gateway/Server (the Fiori Way, although there is the Fiori Client which tries to solve this).

I understand that SAP wants SAPUI5 on the backend because of integration in the SAP software lifecycle management. But it is bought with bad performance and caching issues. A very high price in my opinion! Luckily OpenUI5 is free to be part of real apps.

Comment: how would you integrate the libraries locally? I think this does not work .. ?!